# Google Tag Manager Custom JS - return value when error

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to use custom js in Google Tag Manager to text in 2 scenarios. It is the same text but depending on the page sometime it is hyperlinked and other times it is not

I got the below to work in Chrome console (without the "function()", but when adding to Google Tag manager it requires a "return" to be present. I added before "try" but that caused issues.

```
function() {
try {
        google_tag_manager["GTM-KGLGRKD"].dataLayer.get("gtm.element").parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll("td")[1].querySelector("a").innerText;
        } catch (error) {
       google_tag_manager["GTM-KGLGRKD"].dataLayer.get("gtm.element").parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText;}
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is even the best way to get what i need, but any ideas on making the above compatible with tag manager?

Comment: Do you need this as a Custom HTML to be executed, or as a custom JavaScript function (with a return value) to be used by other tags, triggers or variables?

Comment: I am not sure that these are different scenarios. The innerText of the "td" will be the same with or without the link, since innerText ignores all markup and just returns the text.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, beware that Custom JS code needs a value for every GTM Event, not just for click Events.

I would suggest something like this

```
function() {
  var returnvalue;
  if ({{Click Element}}) {
    try {
      returnvalue = {{Click Element}}.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll("td")[1].querySelector("a").innerText;
    } catch (error) {
      returnvalue = {{Click Element}}.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText;
    }
  }
  return returnvalue;
}
```

{{Click Element}} is an optional Built-in Variable that needs to be enabled in GTM before using it